# How to click the 'Submit' button on DemoQA practice-form?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am trying to write a WebDriverIO test that submits the form here - https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form

The issue I am facing is regarding the 'Submit' button.

On a larger monitor, the 'Submit' button is appearing:

[image: the webpage when viewed on a smaller screen]

On a smaller monitor *(both manually & via automation)*, the 'Submit' button is not visilble, even when scrolling to the bottom of the page. It appears that the footer is covering the button:

[image: the webpage when viewed on a smaller screen]

To try to get around this, I tried to make the window larger by using `await browser.setWindowSize(1300, 1000);`, but I get this error message:

`element click intercepted: Element <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (893, 586). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>`

Is there a way I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using JS `click()` method on element? It should work even if element is not in viewport.

```
browser.execute("arguments[0].click();", submitElement);
```